# How to prevent 'pressing enter' in an input to trigger an event ? Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, keyup

I have an input and an appended button. The click on button calls some function. But I don't want this function to be called when user 'presses enter key'. On the other hand, I want on keyup in this input to call some other function. SO I put

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#id', function(e){
        call();//calling some function
        if (e.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();//I also tried to return false
        }
     });
```

But it doesn't seem to work, someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#id', function(e){
    if (event.keyCode != 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        call();//calling some function
    }
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Still not working and I have this message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: try to change the identificators

Comment: Sorry what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @Newben the problem is not in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#id', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();//I also tried to return false
    }else{
         call();//calling some function
    }
 });
```

Comment: Still not working and I have this message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: What is `#id` in your document? Is this unique to this elem or anyother elem also has same id.

Comment: how did you get this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ` after inputing something

Comment: This is because the call() function returns 'invalid' when the input is not the right one

Answer (score 0):

Don't use keyup, since the form is send on keydown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switch .call() function to a simple alert(), just for tests purpose. @Oyeme and @Jai code seems to work properly.